# how to update WindowViewModel when there is a change in StatusBarViewModel

Tags: wpf, mvvm

I have two ViewModels WindowViewModel & StatusBarViewModel. i want to updatethe property StatusBarVM in WindowViewModel when there is a change in StatusBarViewModel instance

Following is the property in WindowViewModel

```
public StatusBarViewModel StatusBarVM
```

Answer (score 1):

The [MVVM Light Toolkit](http://mvvmlight.codeplex.com/) provides a Messenger class that is designed for exactly this purpose.  Here's a sample on how to use it for VM to VM communication: http://chriskoenig.net/2010/07/05/mvvm-light-messaging/.

Comment: To do that would require that one VM know about the other in order to call methods on it.  Not sure that's the best way to do it.  AS I understand it, Commands are more designed to enable the View talk back to the ViewModel, not for one VM to talk to another VM...

Answer (score 0):

use the eventaggregator from prism. You dont have to use the whole prism library...just that part. I have used this very successfully in an enterprise app that I am working on...

Comment: Could you please share any sample application of prism using eventaggregator